# Compute the sum of products, subtracting a fixed number from each line

Tags: google-sheets

I want to do something like `=sumproduct(C3:C,H3:H)` but for each line I want to subtract a fixed quantity (let's say it's in A1) before doing the product, like this:

```
(A1-C3)*H3
+ (A1-C4)*H4
+ (A1-C5)*H5
+ ...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=A1*count(C3:C)-sumproduct(C3:C,H3:H)
```

as adjusted for your language and locale.

ASSUMES no blanks, text or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like

```
=sumproduct((A1 -C3:C)*H3:H)
```

or

```
=sumproduct((A1 -C3:C),H3:H)
```

Comment: But there's only one value in one cell: A1, not a whole column to iterate. It should use A1 at every step of the SUMPRODUCT that's what I can't figure out to do.